# More uses for bacon grease

Tags: waste, reuse

We (my family) consume good amounts of bacon which produce a lot of bacon grease. I don't like wasting anything that I could reuse or repurpose, including this.
I use this byproduct in many different ways, including:

- **cooking**. Filtered it can be used in cooking other foods or greasing the pans.
- **pet food**. Mixed with other foods, it is a good addition to the animals' diet.
- **lubricant**. Good for certain tools, or snow sleds.
- **candles**. Good source of light while camping or in the back yard.

I'd like to find out more uses, if any, of this "unwanted" byproduct, the bacon grease.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also "wash" the grease to remove meat bits and smoke flavor and use it for soapmaking. Even if you can't get all the smoke scent out, bacon-scented anything is in style these days, so the bars might still make good gifts.  ;-)

Here is [a link to a process for rendering tallow](http://www.motherearthnews.com/homesteading-and-livestock/soap-making-with-tallow-zmaz72jfzfre.aspx#axzz2yzIEoMf9) that should also work for bacon grease.  The basic process works by placing the grease into a pot (crockpots work especially well) and covering it with enough water to submerge the fat chunks or grease.  Let it cook on low for a time, cool it off, lift the fat from the top of the pan, pour out the remaining water and meat bits, and repeat until you get a product that's clean enough for your uses.